# XPath: Matching a text between two similar tags

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, scrapy, lxml, text-parsing

I'm trying to scrape a website with messy structure, the text I'm requiring is laying between the first 5 consecutive br tags (No more and no less, exactly 5) and the following 2 consecutive br tags.
It looks like this:

```html
<p class="A">
"Some text"
<br>
"Some text"
<br>
<br>
"Some text"
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
"Required text"
<br>
"Required text"
<br>
"Required text"
<br>
<br>
</p>
```

Comment: You didn't specify your desired output XML, so this question is un-answerable by now.

Comment: The desired output is the text in the "Required text" text nodes

Comment: probably just split it on <br> and treat it like an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrapy converts `<br>` tags to newline characters, so you can just extract the whole text and split it at 5 newline characters:

```
> text = sel.xpath('//text()').extract()
['\n"Some text"\n', '\n"Some text"\n', ...]
> values = ''.join(text).split('\n\n\n\n\n')[1]
'\n"Required text"\n\n"Required text"\n\n"Required text"\n\n\n'
> values.strip().split('\n\n')
['"Required text"', '"Required text"', '"Required text"']
```